# Ping yes, Internet no

Tags: networking, internet, virtualization, ping

I installed XenServer 7 and created a Ubuntu 16.04 VM from the template. (I'm currently trying on 14.04 because I read somewhere that 16.04 had a bug, but still exactly the same symptoms)

Problem is:
1)I can't connect to the internet but I can ping e.g. google. (ip and www.google.com)
2)I don't know how to show you the output of different things, because I can't copy-paste from the VM in XenCenter to the computer on which I'm running XenCenter.

Regarding 1:

- I didn't change anything in XenServer. XenCenter shows me under Server->Networking Tab that Network 0 (NIC 0)is connected and XenServer itself has access to the internet (wget works). In the lower part it shows me that it got an ip through dhcp which is fine.
- In the VM -> Network tab it shows that device 0 is active and connected to NIC 0, but ip-adress unknown. (However when I ifconfig on the guest, it shows me that it did get an OK ip from dhcp)
- when I ping www.google.com on the guest, it works fine 0% package loss, however when i ping -s (anything above 72) www.google.com it won't work anymore
- when I route, I get my correct router adress in the first line
- when i ifconfig, i see that packets are coming and going, 0 errors.
  btw: MTU:1500
- i can't connect to any website in firefox
- I can ping my host from my guest, i can also ping my router from my guest, but i can't ping other computers on the network from my guest (i'm running xencenter from another computer on the same network as the computer i installed xenserver on)
- during the installation of ubuntu (be it 16 or 14 was the same problem) it wouldnt progress past file xx of xx until i disconnected the network cable from the host machine for the remainder of the installation.
- i still can't apt-get update because it hangs at "getting headers"

Regarding 2:

I'd like to show you copy-pasted output but I don't know how to get it "out" of the little vm window in xencenter

If anybody knows what the problem might be, please let me know.

have a nice day,

marc

Comment: So what happens why you try to `telnet google.com 80`

Comment: Hi, when i do that i get " trying *some ip6?" then "connected to google.com" then "escape key is ^" then nothing and finally "connection closed by foreign host"

Comment: you need to `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop` in ubuntu guest to be able to copy past from guest<>host looks like connection is there and working can you ping your router with 72 bytes ? ifconfig shows few different error counters for TX and RX are they all at 0?